# Methods to share data between two classes

Tags: android

I'm writing an application that has to share data between the two classes. I have tried to use getter and setter methods but data don't remain stored. Using Intent I saw that when I going to receive data the function getIntent() is deprecated with API over 16.

There's any another method to pass data between classes?

Comment: You can use the bundle concept of sharing data between classes

Comment: Can you make me an example?

Comment: Sure @Gioele..I will write the example

Comment: `getIntent()` is not deprecated in `Activity` .`Intent.getIntent()` is deprecated ..

Answer (score 2):

you can save your data in shred preference like this :-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

    public static boolean isUserLoggedOut(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("id_logged_in", true);
    }

    public static void setUserLoggedOut(Context ctx, Boolean value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putBoolean("id_logged_in", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public static boolean isRequestLoad(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("requestLoad", false);
    }

    public static void setRequestLoad(Context ctx, Boolean value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putBoolean("requestLoad", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

to Save Data:-

```
setUserLoggedOut(this, true);
```

to get Data:-

```
isUserLoggedOut(this);
```

you can create your own getter and setter in this class and save data where from you want and get data from where you want

Comment: Now I try and let you know

Comment: appreciate the answer if it helps you

Comment: is there any problem in my suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Bundle concept,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppcompatActivity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = findViewByID(R.id.button);

   b.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("data1","Hello");
        i.putExtra("data2","Android");
        startActivity(i);

 }

}
```

Now use the Bundle concept in the class where you want to receive the data

```
 public class SecondActivity extends AppcompatActivity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

   if(b != null){
   String one = b.getString("data1");
   String two = b.getString("data2");

   Log.e("dataUsingBundle",one + "\n" + two);

   }


}
```

Let me know if you have any query.